# 3.3V Oscillator AC couple to 1.5 Vp-p input

Tags: oscillator

I'm using [MICRF220](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/MICRF220) (origin from MICREL, now Microchip, Sadly, I can't find a suitable place to ask my question. It seems Microchip has not a suitable forum for this chip yet!!!) It can receive external reference input. But it only give specification for AC couple.

[image]

1. May I use DC coupling?
2. If using AC coupling, I only have OSC with 3.3V output. So, I have two choice, one is a resistor divider followed by a coupling capacitor. Another is simply a series resistor followed by a coupling capacitor. Which is better?
3. Any better replacement for this chip?

Comment: What are you doing that a crystal and two caps as shown in the data sheet will not work?

Comment: The chip has built in capacitors to ground whose value are unknown, so if I use simply a crystal, I may need to tune the external capacitors to get the correct frequency.

Comment: I'd expect that 10pF will get you pretty close.  I've made tons of atmege328P, 1284P, and 2560 based boards, with different sources/form factors of 16 MHz crystals, and all worked fine with 22 pF caps, both thru hole and SMD.  I bet you will find this is similar.  Placement is critical - crystal and caps very close to the chip, ground plane under them on both sides of the board, and no active signals under the chip (infrequent activity is fine, like Reset).

Comment: If you scroll down in the datasheet, they have an eval board layout and parts list with manufacturer, values and ratings for 433.92 MHz and 315 MHz.  Follow that and you should be good to go. https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/268/micrf220-779198.pdf

Comment: Microchip still offers an Eval board for that chip.  Mouser.com shows them backordered, with availability Dec 26.  $40.99 USD each, I don't know why so expensive.  Might be the RSSI and squelch? MICRF220-433-EV.  315 MHz MICRF220-315-EV is available now.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to make your question a bit more clear by stating what the MICRF220 does, it's a "300 MHz to 450 MHz ASK/OOK receiver".

This is the typical application diagram:
[image]

Your question is about the (clock) reference input, it has a Crystal connected in the diagram above. The question is, what's inside the chip connected to RO1 and RO2. Fortunately the datasheet answers that on page 11:

[image]

This is a fairly typical example of a crystal oscillator circuit inside many ICs. If you want to apply an external clock you could try to input a clock signal (with a voltage that varies between the voltage at the IC's supply pins) at pin RO2. I find the suggestion of applying the clock to RO1 as is done in the datasheet a bit strange as that would work against the inverter that is present between RO1 and RO2.

You could just try this with a current limiting resistor (so no AC coupling) in series with the clock so that you cannot damage anything. I would apply the clock to RO2 via a 10 kohm resistor. Then measure with an oscilloscope at RO1, if you get a large clock signal at RO1 then that's good. If not try applying the signal at RO1 and try if you get a clock at RO2.

So yes, you can use DC coupling but try that first with a series resistor of 10 kohm.
The AC coupling is probably only needed when the signal is directly (without series resistor) applied to RO1 as RO1 is internally biased to a DC voltage needed for the crystal oscillator circuit to work.

Comment: Yes, it's a little strange to input to RO1. In many MCU which can accept DC coupling, they usually has a internal register to set to turn off the internal OSC, when using external OSC source. But in MICRF220, there is no place to configure, so have to input directly from RO1.

Answer (score 1):

If they are only specifying AC coupling it is very likely because the node is DC-biased to whatever the IC needs to operate. DC-coupling would disturb such bias.

You have a third choice that is likely to be better and much less problematic: a purely capacitive divider.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbjVX3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I know a bunch of PLL chips with so called 'self-biased' CMOS input, which can receive both DC and AC coupling. The only difference is this chip has built in capacitors to ground.

Comment: Won't this will overdrive the osc at starting up?

Comment: @diverger why? It is just a divider using capacitors instead of resistors. It theoretically has an infinite frequency response starting at DC. The actual DC level and frequency response will be set by the MICRF220 and its input impedance.

Comment: You know, all OSC will specify how much load capacitance it can drive without degrade the rising/falling edge. The capacitor divider will draw current under square wave input, right?

Comment: Of course. Just as much as a resistive divider with the same impedance, and there is no reason for the capacitors to be more than a dozen pF. But that brings up a good point, just with the internal load capacitance in that node, even a 30ohm resistor could put the cutoff frequency below what is required. A single ~10pF capacitor might be all that is needed.